# How to view all the products with thumbnail pictures, prices, etc in Virtuemart 3.4.5?

Tags: virtuemart, database, images

trying to see the entire datebase of all the products with a thumbnail image as well as the quantity, price, etc of each product.VirtueMart 3.4.5
Does anyone know if it's possible?
Thank you

Comment: Is the 3.4.5 the version of Joomla? if so you must update immediately to avoid having your site compromised.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such a thing as Virtuemart 3.4.5. Latest version of it is 3.0.12.

VM does have a built-in view (menu type Virtuemart | Category Layout) to list all products in some category, and you just choose Top Level Category to list all products in all children cats.

There are also bunch of other options in that view to adjust to your liking.